# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

While trying to fetch values in a class component I am getting the below error.
Here I am trying to get data from an API Gateway.
The goal is to pick each attribute from JSON response and display them in a frontend dynamic table.

Can someone please help me out in fixing it? Thanks

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

**Code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from '../../axios'

export default class users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []    
        };
    }
    getUsersData() {
        axios
            .post(`/`, { ParentId: 'ou-wmno-yeeol4ok' })
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                const users = data.Accounts.map(u =>
                    <div>
                    <p>{u.Id}</p>
                    </div>
                    )

                    this.setState({
                        users
                    })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getUsersData()
    }
    
    render() {
         return (
            <div>
             {this.state.users}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**JSON Data as API Response:**

```
{
    "Accounts": [
        {
            "Id": "2556",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:organizations::2556:account/ooabc/2556",
            "Email": "2556@aws.test.aws",
            "Name": "test-account",
            "Status": "SUSPENDED",
            "JoinedMethod": "CREATED",
            "JoinedTimestamp": "2021-07-13T14:58:23.197000+00:00"
        },
    ],
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "131462d1-47b2-4c19-aed0-8a30fb6859bd",
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "131462d18a30fb5959bd",
            "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
            "content-length": "3527",
            "date": "Mon, 13 Sep 2021 15:42:52 GMT"
        },
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you actually check in this part `const data = res.data;` that the `res.data` really has the data properly? Your API response seems to indicate that, but it's good to check.

Comment: Yes it does fetch the data properly. The only problem is when I try to pick individual  attribute in the JSON file. I tested it using console.log(data) and it worked.

Comment: Can't help you much then unfortunately, but that would strongly suggest the data isn't in the format shown in your OP. If the data has `Accounts` property, then that `data.Accounts.map` should work, but if that doesn't work then it clearly doesn't have the `Accounts` property. Are you completely sure the data isn't for example in an array?

Answer (score 0):

thanks, everyone- I think I figured it out by using JSON Parser.

```
    getUsersData() {
        axios
            .post(`/`, { ParentId: 'ou-wmno-yeeol4ok' })
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data
                const valuesArray = JSON.parse(data)
                console.log(valuesArray)

                const users = valuesArray.Accounts.map(u =>
                    <tr key={u.Id}>  
                    <td>{u.Name}</td>
                    <td>{u.Arn}</td>
                    <td>{u.Id}</td>
                    <td>{u.Email}</td>
                    <td>{u.JoinedMethod}</td>
                    <td>{u.JoinedTimestamp}</td>
                    <td>{u.Status}</td>
                    </tr>
                    )

                    this.setState({
                        users
                    })

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

usually fetching data is done using the "get" method and not with the "post" method

Comment: True, but it's unlikely to be the OP's problem assuming they gave their API response correctly. 'Post' methods are sometimes used to fetch data because 'get' methods can't have body in the request (or well they can, but it's ignored).